# Throw error (with IntelliSense) when a specified string or value is equal to something

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

Is it possible to throw / display an error in Visual Studio, showing as a design-time error (with or without IntelliSense) when a specified variable is equal to something?

For example, I have a Class Library and a win form. If I import the class Library and declare the Class Library Code and write a specific file path I want to throw an error in visual studio.

**Win Form Code:**

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub RunTest
        ' I want to throw an error here if the string
        ' is equal to = "C:\Users\Downloads\Test.jpg"
        Dim Testing As New Test("C:\Users\Downloads\Test.jpg")
    End Sub
```

**Class Library Code:**

```vb
Public Class Test

    Private Image As Bitmap

    ' If possible here is where I believe I need to throw the error.
    Public Sub New(ByVal FileName As String) 
        Image = DirectCast(Bitmap.FromFile(FileName), Bitmap)
    End Sub

End Class
```

***This is what I have been trying:***

```vb
    ' I wish it was possible to do in the way of:
    Public Sub New(ByVal FileName As String) 
        If FileName = "C:\Users\Downloads\Test.jpg" Then Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid")
        Image = DirectCast(Bitmap.FromFile(FileName), Bitmap)
    End Sub
```

Any input or help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear to me *when* you want the checking to be. Is this meant to occur within Visual Studio, showing as a design-time error? If so, an exception won't help as that's an *execution time* path. If you want to do code analysis, you may want to look at Roslyn... but it's unclear at the moment.

Comment: How is this related to C#? Please try to not use tags that are not really relevant to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of writing it in C# first and forgot to remove the tag. It is now removed.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want the exception to occur within Visual Studio, showing as a design-time error. I would love for it to be an exception during the execution time as well.

Comment: With this: `Dim Testing As New Test("C:\Users\Downloads\Test.jpg")`, your class will be initialized at run-time, not design-time. Maye you want to expose components that can be configured through the Properties panel? Or a custom Property Grid?

Comment: @Jimi Thank you Jimi, that could be a solution, to verify the path during runtime. However, you do not know if it is possible to notify the user if the string is "incorrect" during design-time?

Comment: Well, yes, of course it's possible. If you set the value of a component (think about a UserControl, for example) through the Property grid, you can throw the exception if the value is not acceptable. The exception is raised at design time, as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Throw New ArgumentException` will take effects during runtime, but not design-time. The intellisense won't work for this situation.

Not sure your original requirement, if all you want to do is to get a warning which Intellisense can recognize during design-time, you may get some help from  [ObsoleteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=netframework-4.8#examples).

You can set this attribute to the Test Class or the method within it. And if your winform app calls code from that method, intellisense will display a warning like this to give you reminders:

[image]